# Track multi-touch events to JSON in Android

Tags: android, pointers, multi-touch

I've been fighting this problem for a while now and thought I'd ask for some advice.

The purpose of this code is to generate a Json file with the information about how the user moved in the app. Everytime I get a touch event, I write to an arraylist of Json objects with the following information:
{"action", "timestamp", "index", "y", "x"}

The action is what kind of action it is (down, up, etc.), timestamp is the time from the start of the touch recording, index is supposed to be what finger, (x,y) is the position of the finger.

The problem however, is that I can't seem to make it work with multi-touch. Eventually this Json file will be used to make a video, showing the movements of the user. One finger works perfectly but when there's several fingers involved, I need to have the information about what finger this specific data comes from.

Currently, it tracks a finger and if I use another finger, it will start to track that instead, ignoring the first one.

```
public void writeTouchJSON(MotionEvent event, float time) {
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        String action;
        action = new String();
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            action = "down";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            action = "up";
            break;
        default:
            action = "" + event.getActionMasked();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
            //int index = event.getPointerId(i);
            object.put("x", (int) event.getX(i)); // X-pos of finger
            object.put("y", (int) event.getY(i)); // Y-pos of finger
            object.put("timestamp", (int) (0.000001*(time - timeAtAppLaunch))); // Time since recording started
            object.put("action", action); // What kind of action ("up", "down" or a constant)
            object.put("index", i + 1); // What finger
        }

        Log.d("Wrote JSON to list", object.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("ERROR: json.", ""+e);
    }
    jsonobjects.add(object);
}
```

I hope the code attached is enough. In the method

```
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

I check if the app is recording, if it is I send event to logTouchEvents(event) which eventually ends up in the writeTouchJSON method.

My personal theory is that I mess up the meaning of pointers. From what I've understood a pointer is a finger? So an event has an array of pointers where 0 will give you information about the first finger who touched the screen, 1 about the second, etc. but maybe this is wrong?

If you're interested in why I'm doing this it's because I'm making a user experience testing apk for school where you can record how a person navigates through your app and get a video displaying this.

Thank you for your time! Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the for loop each variable is getting overwriten by its previous value. You should create an array with one element for each pointer (finger).

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy... I changed so that I create the JSONObject within the for loop and add it to the list of jsonobjects at the end of the loop. Would you agree on this solution?